# Custom function with check constraint SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I working with SQL Server 2008 and I have two existing tables, `venues` and `events`.

I am trying to create a custom function with a check constraint to make sure that the integer in the `event_expected_attendance` column in the `events` table is always less than or equal to the `venue_max_capacity` integer in the `venues` table.

I am struggling with the syntax of a custom function as well as the join statement since the check constraint is between two tables.

Thanks for the help! I will answer any additional questions quickly.

Comment: Yes, the two tables would be joined on event_id = event_venue_id

Comment: A trigger will also accomplish this, but it will affect insert/update/delete performance. You build a trigger on the table on the `events` table that checks the `venues` table and raises an error / rolls back invalid values

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As stated by Martin Smith using a check constraint with a UDF has some problems and might have a negative impact on performance, but if you want to try it anyway this code should work:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CheckVenueCapacity (@venue_id int, @capacity int)
RETURNS int
AS 
BEGIN
  DECLARE @retval int
    SELECT @retval = CASE WHEN venue_max_capacity >= @capacity THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    FROM venues
    WHERE venue_id = @venue_id 
  RETURN @retval
END;
GO

ALTER TABLE events 
  ADD CONSTRAINT chkVenueCapacity 
  CHECK (dbo.CheckVenueCapacity(event_venue_id, event_expected_attendance) = 0);
```

Answer (score 17):

You could use a scalar UDF for this but using those in check constraints has well documented problems (e.g. see [Scalar UDFs wrapped in CHECK constraints are very slow and may fail for multirow updates](https://web.archive.org/web/20161010153139/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/06/25/scalar-udfs-wrapped-in-check-constraints-are-very-slow-and-may-fail-for-multirow-updates.aspx) or [Snapshot isolation: A threat for integrity?](https://web.archive.org/web/20170602185202/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2006/07/21/Snapshot-and-integrity-part-1.aspx) series.

It is also possible to get the database engine to enforce this with an indexed view

It needs a helper table with 2 rows as CTEs and `UNION` are not allowed in indexed views. The idea is that the view definition should always return zero rows and this doubles any rows that are returned if there is a violation. Therefore causing a breach of the unique constraint on the view and causing an error to occur and the statement to fail.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TwoNums
  (
     Num INT PRIMARY KEY
  )

INSERT INTO dbo.TwoNums
VALUES      (1),
            (2)
```

Then the view definition

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.PreventOverCapacity
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  SELECT V.Venueid,
         E.EventId,
         E.Expected,
         V.Capacity
  FROM   dbo.Venues V
         JOIN dbo.Events E
           ON E.venueid = V.venueid
              AND E.Expected > V.Capacity
         CROSS JOIN dbo.TwoNums
```

And a unique index on the View

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX [UIX_PreventOverCapacity (Venueid, EventId, Expected, Capacity)]
  ON dbo.PreventOverCapacity(Venueid, EventId, Expected, Capacity)
```

The reason for including all four columns is so that all the required values are shown in the error message.

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.PreventOverCapacity'
> with unique index  'UIX_PreventOverCapacity (Venueid, EventId,
> Expected, Capacity)'.
> The duplicate key value is (1, 97, 110, 100).

Comment: The first link is 11 years old and the SQL given doesn't even compile correctly. The second is 14 years old. I don't believe that anyone should be using such ancient advice to make a decision as to whether using UDFs for check constraints is an issue in 2020.

Comment: @IanKemp well you would be wrong then. The issues are exactly the same. They are still evaluated row by row so can fail as the intermediate state violates the constraint though the state at the end of the statement wouldn't  and still you need to take account of snapshot isolation and add appropriate locking hints. Using the indexed view means you define this declaratively and lever a product feature written correctly that avoids these pitfalls