# Unique constraint based on weeks in a quarter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, relational-database

I am trying to figure out how to apply a unique constraint based on weeks in a quarter.
I have a table that includes `Quarter` (1Q2014, 2Q2014, ...) as well as an `Effective Date` and an `Expiration date`.

I need to allow multiple records for the same `Qtr` as long as `Effective` and `Expiration Dates` do not overlap.

*For example, these records would be legitimate:*

```
Qtr         EffDte          ExpDte
--------------------------------------
1Q2014      2014-01-06      2014-02-03

1Q2014      2014-02-10      2014-02-24

1Q2014      2014-03-03      2014-03-17
```

*While these records would not be legitimate:*

```
Qtr         EffDte          ExpDte
--------------------------------------
1Q2014      2014-01-06      2014-03-24

1Q2014      2014-02-10      2014-03-10

1Q2014      2014-03-03      2014-03-17
```

I am not sure if I need to alter my table design to achieve this goal.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You may want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26693571/custom-function-with-check-constraint-sql-server-2008

Comment: if I were u, I would handle it from application by just validating each new record against its preceding one to avoid performance hassle

Comment: Okay, Thanks! I can validate from the application, I was just hoping to enforce a constraint at the database level to ensure compliance in case of any unexpected errors in the application validation.